# Unable to navigate to home page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-webui

I have an app comprising of home and update screens.

I am unable to navigate back to the home screen from the update screen.

See below code for home screen

```
  // build the list widget
  Widget _buildTaskWidget(task) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.assignment),
      title: Text(task['name']),
      subtitle: Text(task['created_at']),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => UpdateTask(task: task),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

See below code for the update screen

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // final Task task = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Update Task'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              inputWidget(),
              inputWidgetForVendor(),
              inputWidgetForAmount(),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 1, 45, 1),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  child: Text('Update Task', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () async {
                     var res = await updateNewTask(_taskTextInput.text, _vendorTextInput.text,  _amountTextInput.text, id);
                     print(res);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          )// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
      }
```

If I remove the current onPressed function and replace with this below, it works

```
onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); },
```

What am I doing wrong in the initial function?
The update function successfully updates the list items, however I am unable to navigate back.
See below error logs:

```
E/flutter (27123): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
E/flutter (27123): #0      updateNewTask (package:task/repository/services.dart:67:10)
E/flutter (27123): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you also post how are you coming on update screen from home screen? Because that will be important too! Are you using "Navigator.pushReplacement" to go to update screen from home screen?

Comment: your current onPressed is calling an async fuction? have you checked in debug mode if your res variable returns any errors? what does your debug console return in both situations?

Comment: @AmitB10, i have added navigation to update screen.

Comment: the function successfully updates list items but I am unable to navigate back.  See below error log:E/flutter (27123): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
E/flutter (27123): #0      updateNewTask (package:task/repository/services.dart:67:10)
E/flutter (27123): <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: @biggest_boy: This is not a Navigator.pop issue, it's working on my end, its definitely coming by your method only.

Comment: thanks, the issue was my method, ive fixed it and its working now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe outsourcing your async update function is a simple solution at this point, when you want to instantly go back to your home screen. You could print the update directly in the function then.

Just leave onpressed() as it is.

```
onPressed: () {
  updateNewTask(_taskTextInput.text, _vendorTextInput.text,  _amountTextInput.text, id);
  Navigator.pop(context);
},
```